# Need ideas on retrieving data from a website

Tags: screen-scraping, external, web, sites

I'm stumped and need some ideas on how to do this or even whether it can be done at all.

I have a client who would like to build a website tailored to English-speaking travelers in a specific country (Thailand, in this case). The different modes of transportation (bus & train) have good web sites for providing their respective information. And both are very static in terms of the data they present (the schedules rarely change). Here's one of the sites I would need to get info from: [train schedules](http://www.railway.co.th/home/srt/timetable/northlinetxt.asp?lenguage=Eng) The client wants to provide users the ability to search for a beginning and end location and determine, using the external website's information, how they can best get there, being provided a route with schedule times for the different modes of chosen transport.

Now, in my limited experience, I would think the way to do that would be to retrieve the original schedule info from the external site's server (via API or some other means) and retain the info in a database, which can be queried as needed. Our first thought was to contact the respective authorities to determine how/if this can be done, but this has proven to be problematic due to the language barrier, mainly.

My client suggested what is basically "screen scraping", but that sounds like it would be complicated at best, downloading the web page(s) and filtering through the HTML for relevant/necessary data to put into the database. My worry is that the info on these mainly static sites is so static, that the data isn't even kept in a database to build the page and the web page itself is updated (hard-coded) when something changes.

I could really use some help and suggestions here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Screen scraping is always problematic IMO as you are at the mercy of the person who wrote the page. If the content is static, then I think it would be easier to copy the data manually to your database. If you wanted to keep up to date with changes, you could then snapshot the page when you transcribe the info and run a job to periodically check whether the page has changed from the snapshot. When it does, it sends an email for you to update it.

The above method could also be used in conjunction with some sort of screen scaper which could fall back to a manual process if the page changes too drastically.

Ultimately, it is a case of how much effort (cost) is your client willing to bear for accuracy

Comment: Yeah - your answer was pretty much what I was expecting to hear. Of course, if anyone has any other ideas, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Would a cURL script (which I have never worked with) be of any help/benefit in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this for the following site: http://www.buscatchers.com/ so it's definitely more than doable! A key feature of a web scraping solution for travel sites is that it must send you emails if anything went wrong during the scraping process.  On the site, I use a two day window so that I have two days to fix the code if the design changes.  Only once or twice have I had to change my code, and it's very easy to do.

As for some examples.  There is some simplified source code here: http://www.buscatchers.com/about/guide.  The full source code for the project is here: https://github.com/nicodjimenez/bus_catchers.  This should give you some ideas on how to get started.

Comment: Thanks for the links, nicodjimenez. Those'll help.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell that the data is dynamic, it's to well structured. It's not hard for someone who is familiar with xpath to scrape this site.